# How do I determine if USE NETWORK PROVIDED VALUES is checked in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have searched n googled everything possible related to this but did not quite find anything concrete. How can i determine if the option USE NETWORK PROVIDED VALUES in the date/time settings is checked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
    android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME
```

Is Deprecated

People who were searching answer for this use this

```
android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME);
```

BTW, Matthias Robbers, Thanks another ton :)